The distance between skew diagonals on two adjacent faces of a cube.
Given a cube with edge length  a , diagonals are drawn on two adjacent faces, and these diagonals do not originate from the same vertex. Prove that the distance between these diagonals is equal to 1/3 of the length of the cube’s space diagonal.
I need a solution by geometric means ONLY.
I have solved it already using coordinates and coordinates are allowed but my solution was based on the minimal distance between points on those faces and required partial differential equations to solve it.
If only I could use one variable function solution with coordinates will be fine as well although geometric solution is still welcome.

Can you show us your efforts?

We’re not allowed to use coordinates?

HINT: a diagonal of the cube is intersected by two parallel equilateral triangles, having as sides the diagonals of the faces.

Thanks @Intelligentipauca, I'll give it a thought.

Thanks @bubba, coordinates are allowed, see my amended post, please.

Thanks @Dominique, see my amended post where my efforts are described.

Imagine an axis through the center of a pair of opposite sides of the cube. Rotate a diagonal of any of remaining four sides through 90 degree and look at the successive positions of  center points of the diagonal.

@Intelligentipauca your hint has helped me to solve this, thanks, apologies for responding so late, I just forgot to confirm. All the best
